# Not able to connect to mySql in spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am creating an spring boot application using jpa unable to get root cause of this. But when I  run as java application, I get following error in console, no chance of table getting created in db. I tried removing m2 repository and trying to build again,  but still same .Could anyone please help

```
 The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Aditya.Jadhav\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Aditya.Jadhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/Aditya.Jadhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/Aditya.Jadhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/Aditya.Jadhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Aditya.Jadhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/Aditya.Jadhav/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]
 Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782) [spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:404) [spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:319) [spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1275) [spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1263) [spring-boot-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.bookstore.BookstoreApplication.main(BookstoreApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:900) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:931) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1841) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.M1.jar:5.2.0.M1]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect  ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:160) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect  ]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:136) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:129) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect  
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.2.Final.jar:5.4.2.Final]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

*application.properties*

```
server.port = 8078
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstoredatabase
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = root
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true;
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

*pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.bookstore</groupId>
    <artifactId>bookstore</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bookstore</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>

        </dependency>                       
        <dependency> 
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId> 
        </dependency>               
        <dependency>
         <groupId>mysql</groupId> 
         <artifactId> mysql-connector-java</artifactId> 
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

*User.java*

````
import ...
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name ="email", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    //getters ,setters, no dc/pc    
}```
````

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: my sql version5.7.21

Comment: The error is ca not find the class org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect. Add the required hibernate dependency in the pom.

Answer (score 2):

Read your the error-logs carefully:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect  ] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

It is unable to load class **`org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect`**. In your application.properties file you have mentioned this class. It will allow Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for MySQL. This class comes in `hibernate-core` jar. Since you have not mentiond hibernate-core dependency in your pom.xm, hibernate-core jar is not present in your project. Add following dependency to your pom.xml file.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding this or removing this has no effect. Spring boot Application starts but  table user (along with columns)is  not created  automatically in  database bookstoredatabase. I also dont think no need for hibernate-core  as I  have used spring-data-jpa